# Cómo sumar valores que están dentro de los elementos con el mismo "name" en una tabla? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, html-tabla

Estoy haciendo una tabla en la que quiero sumar los valores que estan en los `input` con el `name="valores"` y presentar el resultado en el `input "calculo"`. El problema esta en que quiero poner la funcion de añadir y eliminar filas, y como quiero poner esa funcion entonces no le puedo poner una variable independiente a cada fila, por eso creo que debo obtener todos los valores con  `document.getElementsByName("valores")`  y sumar los valores que se ingresan en los inputs con el `name="valores"` y mandar el resultado al `input "calculo"`. Agradeceria su ayuda. Si no me he dado a entender me lo haces saber. Que sea especificamente Javascript. Gracias!!

```
<table border="1" class="table" id="tabla">
       <thead class="thead-dark">
           <tr>
               <td>variables</td>
               <td>valores</td>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="articulos" placeholder="ingrese su articulo">
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="valores" placeholder="ingrese su valor">
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="articulos">
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="valores">
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
           <tr>

               <td colspan="1" align="center">TOTAL</td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="calculo">
                   <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="Calcular()">
               </td>
           </tr>

       </tfoot>

   </table>

   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
function Calcular() {
    let valor = document.getElementsByName("valores").value;
    let total = parseInt(valor) + valor
    document.getElementsByName("calculo")[0].value = total;
}
```

Comment: el problema esta en que pueden haber cantidades indefinidas de filas por eso necesito una forma que me permita sumar todos los numeros dentro de esa columna sin tener que asignarle un id a cada una

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrego código comentado.

```js
function Calcular(){
  
  // obtener arreglos de elementos por su nombre
  let elementos = document.getElementsByName('valores');
  
  let total = 0;

  // recorrer el arreglo de elementos
  elementos.forEach(e => {
    // multiplicar el valor del elemento por 1 para convertirlo
    // en número
    let numero = e.value * 1;
    // si el resultado es un número sumarlo al total
    if(!isNaN(numero)) total += numero;
  
  });
  // agregar el total
  document.getElementsByName('calculo')[0].value = total;


}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="table" id="tabla">
       <thead class="thead-dark">
           <tr>
               <td>variables</td>
               <td>valores</td>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="articulos" placeholder="ingrese su articulo">
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="valores" placeholder="ingrese su valor">
               </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="articulos">
               </td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="valores">
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
       <tfoot>
           <tr>

               <td colspan="1" align="center">TOTAL</td>
               <td>
                   <input type="text" name="calculo">
                   <input type="button" value="Calcular" onclick="Calcular()">
               </td>
           </tr>

       </tfoot>

   </table>

   </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias funciono perfecto